# PGP key signature from stranger

Tags: key, gnupg

I received a signature to my key by an unknown person. How should I react?

Signing GPG keys should be a trusty way to declare the real link between key and owner but in this case a person I do not know declared to know me and to have verified the validity of my key.

That's not the case.

Can I remove/block/tag someone's signature to my key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I remove/block/tag someone's signature to my key?

Unfortunately not, that's not possible with the design of OpenPGP and the way the keyservers work.

The other person's signature on your key doesn't actually *mean* anything - certainly not a two-way relationship.

I understand you might be worried that people *think* it means more than it does.

> How should I react?

Is the unknown person a well-known evil person you don't want to be associated with in any way?

If not I wouldn't worry about it.

You've highlighted one of the many confusing or broken things about the web of trust. The technical principle is fine, but in reality few people understand it well enough to know what it's saying.

The plus side is that people aren't likely to read much into your mysterious signer.

## Other reasons people don't use web-of-trust

- it reveals something about who you email, and when you met them (at a key signing party, for example)
- it allows anyone to attach an arbitrary comment to your key (by generating a new key, filling out the UID field and signing & pushing your key.)
- it's unclear what a signature *means*, to the extent that some people actually write signature policies to describe what verification they do.

## My personal approach

This is my approach which doesn't involve the web of trust.

- Treat the keyservers as a free but untrustworthy way of hosting your public key.
- Share your fingerprint widely: in email signatures, social media, website, business card, Signal
- Refer to your key by fingerprint, rather than by a URL to a keyserver
- Always fetch keys with your software by fingerprint, then you get fingerprint-checking for free: e.g. `gpg --recv-keys 'A999 B749 8D1A 8DC4 73E5  3C92 309F 635D AD1B 5517'`
- Don't search the keyservers by name or email. The keys listed could belong to *anyone*.
- Forget short IDs exist. Use long IDs only if you can't use fingerprint.